# calling Intent with startActivityForResult in onActivityResult method and how to handle result

Tags: android

public void onActivityResult(int paramInt1, int paramInt2, Intent paramIntent)
        {
          super.onActivityResult(paramInt1, paramInt2, paramIntent);
          if ((paramInt2 == -1) && (paramInt1 == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE))
          {
            Uri localUri = paramIntent.getData();
            if (localUri != null)
            {
                Uri selectedImage = paramIntent.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

```
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            // Log.e("file path", "" + filePath);
            cursor.close();

            setphoto = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
          Intent localIntent = new Intent(this, MakePhoto.class);
          localIntent.setData(localUri);
          Util.fristPhoto = setphoto;
          localIntent.putExtra("MaxResolution", this.maxResolution);
          startActivityForResult(localIntent, 2);
```

}
}